# Reopening page on Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to reopen same page on Codeigniter. See code below:

```
<?php
class Leads extends CI_Controller
{
public $tempName;
public $tempFrom;
public $tempTo;

public function index() {
    $this->load->model('Lead');
    $leads = $this->Lead->getAllLeads();
    $pageNum = count($leads);
    $this->load->view('main', array('leads' => $leads, 'pageNum' => $pageNum));
}

public function getLeads(){
    $this->load->model('Lead');
    $name = $this->input->post('name');
    $from = $this->input->post('from');
    $to = $this->input->post('to');
    $leads = $this->Lead->getLeads($name, $from, $to);
    $pageNum = count($leads);
    $this->load->view('main', array('leads' => $leads, 'pageNum' => $pageNum));
}
}
?>
```

As you can see, first I open 'main' from 'index()'. In main, I call 'getLeads()', but my page is not getting updated. Is it because I can't refresh data while on the same page? If yes, how can I work around it?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call a controller from a view.  It sounds like you probably should be using AJAX in your "main" view to get additional data from getLeads().

Comment: I am calling 'view' from Controller. Yes, I am using AJAX. But the page is not getting refreshed.

Comment: In your question, you said "In main, I call 'getLeads()", which is why it sounded like you're calling a controller from a view.  AJAX is not going to refresh your page, and you shouldn't want to refresh it.  Instead of having getLeads() return a whole new "main" view, you should just have it give you the data you need to show and then you can append it to the HTML of your initial "main" page.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, Ben, I tried it. I created new page called 'list'. Then in AJAX, I appended it to my current 'main'. It worked. Now, the problem is that when I try to create page numbers, I am not able to attach to the form, because the data in 'list'! So it gets refreshed, 'list' appears, but 'main' is lost with the form in it. Is there a way to grab (pull) data from 'list' and make it accessible to 'main'?

Comment: As you said, I received 'main', it gets appended, but on top of the 'main', so I have two forms on the screen!

Comment: Right, you need to not have getLeads() return a duplicate "main" view.  You should have it return a much more simplified view with just the data you want appended or replaced on your main page.

Comment: It is working. Now how can I get a certain data from the 'list' to use it in 'main's form? Because currently everything is in 'list', while 'main' is only a form.

Comment: If you had 'list' return some JSON, you could simply do whatever you needed with that data and insert it anywhere you needed on the page with javascript/jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Option A:

redirect with js to the same function you have, but change the method to get (send params in the URL and get them on the server with `$this->input->get()`).

Option B:

Since you are posting to `getLeads` I assume you are using ajax. And since you are using ajax, you should return an url or data to render on your website. Maybe you could use `$this->session->set_flashdata('leads',$leads)` and `$this->session->set_flashdata('pageNum',$pageNum)` , send an url to another controller function, extract leads and pageNum `$this->session->flashdata('leads')` & `$this->session->flashdata('pageNum')` and then render the view?

Responding with load view will not automatically set the html to what you get.

Comment: I tried this: $this->session->set_flashdata('leads', $leads), then did $this->load->view('main'); But nothing I get in 'main' when I do $this->session->flashdata('leads'). :( Flashdata is not working...

Comment: var_dump works, but not getting assigned to $leads in 'main'.